# How to make karma work with a webpack, Angular2, and SASS project?

Tags: sass, angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I am using [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and I have my stylesheets as SASS. Everything is working perfectly, but when I try to run karma tests it fails giving me this error

```
ERROR in ./src/app/widgets/message/messages.scss
Module parse failed: d:\ui_widgets-A2\src\app\widgets\message\messages.scss Unexpected token (6:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:22)
    at Parser.pp.raise (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:920:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1483:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1462:73)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1976:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1754:188)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1648:21)
    at Parser.parse (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1616:17)
    at Object.parse (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:882:44)
    at Parser.parse (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at d:\ui_widgets-A2\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:439:3)
 @ ./src/app/widgets/message/message.component.ts 9:431-457
```

I tried to install [karma-sass-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sass-preprocessor) and [karma-scss-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-scss-preprocessor) but nothing seems to work. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer is pretty trivial, I had

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
  }
```

in my `webpack.common.js` and for some reason I thought that `webpack.test.js` was getting it as well,  but as it turns out I should have also added it to `webpack.test.js`

Comment: in my case processing hangs on 62%, but if I use loaders: ['raw-loader', 'style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader'] , processing being done but scss style is not loading.

Comment: I have the related question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818744 , can you please look into it , if you can help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using angular cli there you have nice examples with bootstrapping project.

https://cli.angular.io/

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#css-preprocessor-integration

But here you can find some answers regarding your problem:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/136

Comment: The github issue is about sass with the project itself not Karma